# How many points/pixels are added to a CALayer given a shadowRadius?

Tags: core-graphics, calayer, gaussian

I would like to render a `CALayer` to a `UIImage` including the shadow if any is present on the `CALayer`.

This all works fine except that I cannot determine (other than empirically) what the relation between `shadowRadius` and point/pixel might be.

That is, I create a parent `CALayer` with a transparent background and an inflated size that would include the target `CALayer`'s shadow. Then I render the parent `CALayer`.

Empirically, it seems I can tightly include the entire shadow for any shadowRadius by setting the parent layer's size to the `{width, height}` of the target layer's `size + 3.75 * shadowRadius.{width,height}`.

It's kind of weird and hackish and I'd like to know the real answer/derivation.

It seems the blur is a guassian blur so this is going to be involved in the answer somehow I suppose...

Using 2 * shadowRadius clearly clips:

[image]

Using 5 * shadowRadius is clearly too large:

[image]

And 3.75 * shadowRadius seems to be spot on (but WHY?!):

[image]

Comment: see Apple's response here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/657925  sad panda :(

Comment: 'There was an error processing your request' :( What did they say, "because screw you, that's why"?

Comment: They said that unfortunately there isn't a really good answer. And that the approximation you found is probably reasonable.